# Add an Element on the top of header.panel.wrapper

Tags: magento2, layout, header

I need to place an element ot the most top of page. the position is exactly on the top of header.panel.wrapper.

[image]

My objection is to have some elements on the the most top of header.

[image]

Any help regarding this issue would be very appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer by myself. here is my default.xml now:

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel.wrapper">
            <block class="Senheng\Def\Block\Html\Topinfo"
                name="senheng.top.info" before="-"/> 
        </referenceContainer>
```